# Resource not found when tailing slash missing Spring cloud Zuul

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix

I am using `spring-cloud-starter-zuul` as a gateway to my multiple applications. When I try to call my `angular2` application with slash `http://localhost:8080/console/` it is working fine but when I call without slash `http://localhost:8080/console` getting `404 (Not Found)` error.

Here is my zuul config

```
zuul:
  routes:
    angui:
      path: console/**
      url: http://localhost:8888/
    service1:
      path: service1/**
      url: http://service1URL
    service2:
      path: service2/**
      url: http://service2URL
```

Answer (score 1):

The trailing slash (`/`) is mandatory. That's not a Zuul behavior but a a underlying Tomcat behavior.

See dsyer's answer: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/919#issuecomment-261173286